# Get more sub level for in menu

Tags: 7, navigation

I'm able to get second level of the main menu by using below code.

```
$menu = '';
$menuItems = menu_tree_page_data('main-menu'); 
foreach($menuItems as $key => $m) {
    if ($m['link']['in_active_trail'] && $menuItems[$key]['below']) {
        $menu = render(menu_tree_output($menuItems[$key]['below']));
   }  
}
print $menu;
```

If I want to get 3rd (like in image below), 4th or 5th level. how this will be done.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is necessary that you want to display this using code?

I have a better solution for you. You can try with this module [Menu Block](https://www.drupal.org/project/menu_block) for above achievement

Comment: ufff! after exhausted and wasted a lot of time and here you come. Thanks block is working as I expected. Thanks again

Comment: [Menu Block](https://www.drupal.org/project/menu_block) doesn't load Level 3 if Level 1 is selected. however, I have just found a [nice_menu](https://www.drupal.org/project/nice_menus) that loads all of child. So I'm gonna add as a answer.

Comment: But [nice_menu](https://www.drupal.org/project/nice_menus) isn't loads when any active_trail exits. It always load. Its neither fits for my requirement.

Comment: <?php $main_menu_tree = menu_tree(variable_get('menu_main_links_source', 'main-menu'));             print drupal_render($main_menu_tree);  ?> Add this on your header menu.

Comment: And disable menu block. This menu_tree help to render all level which you will add in your menu (selected menu)

Comment: Thanks for your effort. It works same as [menu Block](https://www.drupal.org/project/menu_block) do. Your code does same according to comment # 2.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a module named [Nice_Menus](https://www.drupal.org/project/nice_menus) that works for me.